# Archive - same title for the first two posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, archives

I created an archive page called archive.php

Here I include header / footer and this code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : ?>
              <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><a/></h1>
              <?php the_post(); the_content();  ?>
              <br />
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The problem is that when there are more posts for a month, the first two posts have the title and permalink of the first post. How can I fix this?

Anticipated thanks!

**EDIT**

Good advice toscho.

I fixed it, here's the solution:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><a/></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?><br />

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `the_post();` before you use `the_permalink()` or `the_title()`. Both functions work with a global `$post` object that will be set up by `the_post();`.

Comment: I tried this also, but in this case it won't appear all the posts from the chosen month. For example: from 3 posts one is displayed, or from 6 posts 3 are displayed.. how to fix this?

Comment: Please show your code for this version.

Comment: I fixed it, I updated my question, see there the final solution. Thanks toscho (I can't mark your question as useful because of my low score :D )